# Add new data in Async Storage React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Sorry to bother you but Im new at React Native. I can save data in Async Storage with a random key but when I try so save more data in a different key (dince is random) it only displays the new one. I want to display all the data. Heres my code:

When I save

```js
const storeData = async () => {
    let id = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);
    var id33 = id;

    setId3(id33);
    const jsonValue = user + id33 + newdate2 + id33;

    const jsonValue4 = jsonValue;

    await AsyncStorage.setItem("user", jsonValue4);
    //await AsyncStorage.setItem("date", jsonValue2);
    //await AsyncStorage.setItem("id", jsonValue3);
    getData();
    //getData2();

    alert(jsonValue);
};
```

When I read:

```js
const getData = async () => {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
    const value4 = JSON.parse(value);
    setValue2(value4);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because all the values you store on asyncStorage, you've stored on location 'user'
and you're asking your codes to give you back data from location 'user' so it'll give you back the same value you stored in

but if you've putted other values on keys other than 'user' you can get all the keys in a array using

```
var keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
```

and request the values using `multget` api of asyncStorage as below

```
 var keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
 var values = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I got it!

Comment: You're welcome, man.